# JavaScript prototype of Object created by calling Class constructor

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am very new to JavaScript there is one confusing bit I cannot understand:

1. Creating an `Object` by using `class`:

   ```
   class RabbitClass {
     constructor(type) {
       this.type = type;
     }
     speak(line) {
       console.log(`The ${this.type} rabbit says '${line}'`);
     }
   }

   let killerRabbit = new RabbitClass("killer");
   ```
2. Creating an `Object` by using `new` with a `function`:

   ```
   function RabbitFunction(type) {
     this.type = type;
   }

   Rabbit.prototype.speak = function(line) {
     console.log(`The ${this.type} rabbit says '${line}'`);
   };

   let weirdRabbit = new RabbitFunction("weird");
   ```

---

Question:
`weirdRabbit` is created from `RabbitFunction`  in Method two, the output of following:

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(weirdRabbit));
```

> RabbitFunction{speak: function(line){…}}

`killerRabbit` is created using the `RabbitClass` in Method1 the output of following:

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(killerRabbit));
```

> {}

---

Why is there a difference between the two outputs?

`RabbitClass` is also a `function` like the `RabbitFunction` in Method 2.

Are the two things not essentially the same?

Both `functions` create `objects` whose `prototypes` are same as the their own `.prototype` property.

Comment: Yes, they are essentially the same, they only vary in minor details such as the *enumerability* of the prototype methods - which affects `console.log`

Comment: You do have a typo in your function example, since your second statement uses `Rabbit.prototype` rather than `RabbitFunction.protoype`, but assuming that `RabbitFunction` is actually `Rabbit` in the real code, the output makes sense.

Comment: Thanks HereticMonkey removed the typo.

Comment: Thanks Bergi can you give some more information or links about the difference in outputs.